# Mapping value selected in Spinner to other values

Tags: android, spinner

I got a spinner of items, e.g. {Apples, Oranges, Eggs, Bread}. When user selects "Eggs" it's value/cost ($2) would be used in a computation of total cost later. How can I map a value(cost of item) with the item selected by the user in the spinner? I'm a little confused whether it's possible. It seems like it is having 2 values.

Something like:

`double totalExpenses = $23 + (cost of the item user selected)`

**strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="spinner_array">
<item>Apples</item>
<item>Oranges</item>
<item>Eggs</item>
<item>Bread</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid creating your own adapter (sometimes you want this to keep it simple)

Have another array of same size, which has the prices:

```
<string-array name="spinner_array">
   <item>Apples</item>
   <item>Oranges</item>
   <item>Eggs</item>
   <item>Bread</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="spinner_array_values">
   <item>5.99</item>
   <item>6.99</item>
   <item>2.99</item>
   <item>12.99</item>
</string-array>
```

Then, on your event handler, get the selected index of the spinner. Use that index to get the price from the second array.

```
double totalExpenses = $23 + Double.parseDouble(value of spinner_array_values index at the spinner selected index);
```

=== EDIT (code sample) ====

```
int selectedIndex = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
String[] price_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_array_values);
double totalExpenses = 23 + Double.parseDouble(price_array[selectedIndex]);
```

OR

```
double totalExpenses = 23 + Double.parseDouble(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_array_values)[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
```

Comment: Hi, I get what you mean. But how to get the value from spinner_array_values? I'm getting position of spinner_array by using spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(). How do I declare a reference to the string_array_value?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create a custom ArrayAdapter. That would let you use your own class (class Food, for example) as the item in the list.

That way you can do all of your calculations abstracted.

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjAlNfa6obU) may get you started on the right foot.